# cloth simulation is not working properly

Tags: cloth-simulation, collision, particle-nodes

hey all so I have this plane , and I have two object with hair particle system on it , basically the cloth is not really working properly as the hair is going through the cloth , how can I fix this , every object is collision here , just the particle are just going through the plane cloth
thanks [image]

Comment: You can't avoid that, you'll need to use a trick, like an invisible object that will be the real collision object

Comment: yup it worked thank you